# regex failing with no errors

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text in a string called $test:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: testapp (4.2.1 (x86_64/linux))
Content-Length: 125

{"password":"123","email_address":"","name":"j.doe","username":"jd123"}
```

I am trying to write a regular expression in php that will return everything after content-length: 125.
Here's what I have so far:

```
if (preg_match('/^Content\-Length\:[0-9\\n]+([a-zA-Z0-9\{\}\"\:])*/',$test,$result))
{
         var_dump($result[1]);
}
```

I don't get any error messages, but it doesn't find the pattern I've defined in my string. 
I've also tried this pattern:

```
  '/^Content\-Length\:[0-9\\n]+([a-zA-Z0-9{}\"\:])*/'
```

where I tried to remove the escape char infront of the curly braces. But it's still a no go.

Can you tell me what I'm missing? 
Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

my code now looks like this:

```
<?php
$test = "Content-Type: text/plain
Server: kamailio (4.2.1 (x86_64/linux))
Content-Length: 125

{"password":"test123","email_address":"","name":"j.doe","username":"jd123"}";

//if (preg_match('/Content-Length\:[0-9\\n]*([a-zA-Z0-9{}\"\:])*/',$test,$result))
//{      
//         var_dump($result);
//}

preg_match('/({.*})/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
?>
```

That gives me the following error:

> Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/test/test.php on line 31

Line 31 is where I'm trying to echo the matches.

Comment: in your edit you're checking for `$str` instead of `$test` which doesn't match anything

Comment: And you should be seeing other errors because you're breaking out of the string. Try my answer again...

Comment: you've got unmatched whitespace after the literal. Add space after the first : in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = <<<HEREDOC
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: testapp (4.2.1 (x86_64/linux))
Content-Length: 125

{"password":"123","email_address":"","name":"j.doe","username":"jd123"}
HEREDOC;

preg_match('/(\{.*\})/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

The regex here is simply matching a line that begins with `{` and ends with `}`. It's a quick and loose regex, however.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working... please see my edit 1.  thanks!

Comment: you should explain what this does. Also it's not a very good regex for many reasons.

Comment: You need to escape the curly braces at a minimum.

Comment: Indeed, thanks @chris85. It was working fine without escaping (not sure how...) but they are meta chars and need to be escaped.

Comment: The string is multilined so I think you need the 'm' modifier as well. He/she may also want the 's' modifier if that string is ever going to be multilined. Also the [0] is the whole string [1] is the grouping and you need to move the parenthesis inside the curlys. "the string" being the text in the curlys where the '.' is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a big pattern to match everything (which is timeconsuming) - why not use `preg_split` to cut your string into two pieces at your desired location?

```
$string = 'Content-Type: text/plain
   Server: testapp (4.2.1 (x86_64/linux))
   Content-Length: 125

   {"password":"123","email_address":"","name":"j.doe","username":"jd123"}'; 

$parts = preg_split ("/Content-Length:\s*\d+\s*/", $string);

echo "The string i want is '" . $parts[1] . "'";
```

Output:

```
The string i want is '{"password":"123","email_address":"","name":"j.doe","username":"jd123"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the regex altogether because the HTTP header is always separated from the response body by 2 consecutives line breaks.

```
list($headers, $body) = explode("\n\n", $string);
```

Or for windows-style breaks( which by the way are the standard for HTTP headers):

```
list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $string);
```